# append data to an instance of DataFrame placed in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In my problem I am trying to define a DataFrame (*ex*) and to store inside it some values during my computation.

Below is a short example of my problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

def main():
    ex1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp','A'])
    ex2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp','A'])
    str1 = 'hello-1'
    str2 = 'hello-2'
    tcp_hash = { 1 : (ex1, str1), 2 : (ex2, str2) }

    for idx in range(5):
        try:
            (df, str_idx) = tcp_hash.get(idx, None)
            df.append({'Timestamp': idx, 'A': str_idx}, ignore_index=True)
            tcp_hash[idx] = (df, str_idx)
        except TypeError:
            print('TCP Message: {} does not have a parser'.format(idx))

    print(ex1)
    print(ex2)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

As result of my *ex*, i get:

```py
TCP Message: 0 does not have a parser
TCP Message: 3 does not have a parser
TCP Message: 4 does not have a parser
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Timestamp, A]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Timestamp, A]
Index: []
```

instead of:

```py
         Timestamp     A
      0  1             hello-1
```

and

```py
         Timestamp     A
      0  2             hello-2
```

If I understand correctly my problem, then i guess that *ex* inside _tcp_hash_ is a copy of my *ex* instead of a "reference".

How could I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fix your code. Pandas `df.append` will create new object. Therefore, any dataframe result from `append` is not the original `ex1`, `ex2` anymore. You may use `loc` to inline modify the `ex1`, `ex2` as follows

```
def main():
    ex1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp','A'])
    ex2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp','A'])
    str1 = 'hello-1'
    str2 = 'hello-2'
    tcp_hash = { 1 : (ex1, str1), 2 : (ex2, str2) }

    for idx in range(5):
        try:
            (df, str_idx) = tcp_hash.get(idx, None)
            #df.append({'Timestamp': idx, 'A': str_idx}, ignore_index=True)
            df.loc[df.shape[0], :] = {'Timestamp': idx, 'A': str_idx}
            tcp_hash[idx] = (df, str_idx)
        except TypeError:
            print('TCP Message: {} does not have a parser'.format(idx))

    print(ex1)
    print(ex2)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
TCP Message: 0 does not have a parser
TCP Message: 3 does not have a parser
TCP Message: 4 does not have a parser
  Timestamp        A
0  1         hello-1
  Timestamp        A
0  2         hello-2
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I modified my code in order to explain a bit more about the complexity of my question and why i can't use your answer. I am intreasting in a generic solution, since i do not know the exact DataFrame.

Comment: @Eagle: due to mutability of dataframe, `ex1`, `ex2` outside and inside dict are the same objects. However, they initially are all empty. You need to have the code to assign values to them. That is the part which your code is missing.

Comment: I modified my code to what i think you ment. Nether the less it doesn't want to work...

Comment: @Eagle: `df.append` will create a new object. So, after you call it, it is not original `ex1`, `ex2` object anymore. I edited the answer to use other method. Check my edited

Comment: Is there a possibility to improve the performance? since the operation "assignment" consume time. Will prealloc  of space to the DataFrame improve in something?

Comment: @Eagle: It is surely very slow since you use loops and assign row by row. Prealloc space won't help. You need to use numba or redesign your logic to use vectorized operation. I am aware of numba, but don't have much knowledge of it. Here the link to numba https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: my dictionary (tcp_hash) contains between 20 and 30 elements. I try to make my code general, which seems to cost me preference. I could use if-else statements and then use the skip the dictionary. Nether the less, the code will be longer...